# how can i clear arraylist when my app in onpause and recive again when in onresume

Tags: android

i use this code but its not work completely

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(!iD.isEmpty()&&!subject.isEmpty()&&!content.isEmpty()&&!more.isEmpty()&&!picture.isEmpty()&&!type.isEmpty()) {
        iD.clear();
        subject.clear();
        more.clear();
        content.clear();
        type.clear();
        picture.clear();


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the o/p you are getting

Comment: where are your array data?

Comment: Improve your issue with your code and more cleary problem

Comment: what do you mean by receive again in onresume? you mean the same data?

Answer (score 0):

If some array is empty the other will not be cleared, just do:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

        iD.clear();
        subject.clear();
        more.clear();
        content.clear();
        type.clear();
        picture.clear();  

}
```